# Why does Git ignore not work for __pycache__ folder?

Tags: git, gitignore

I have 3 paths that I'm trying to ignore in my `.gitignore` file:

```
aws_scripts/python/aws_tools/__pycache__/
.vscode/
aws_scripts/output_files/
aws_scripts/source_files/
```

Everything gets ignored except for `aws_scripts/python/aws_tools/__pycache__/`

```
git status
On branch develop
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/develop'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   aws_scripts/python/aws_tools/__pycache__/ec2_mongo.cpython-39.pyc

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        .gitignore

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

If I comment out the lines in `.gitignore`, those directories are there again in `git status`.
`.gitignore` with lines commented out:

```
#aws_scripts/python/aws_tools/__pycache__/
#.vscode/
#aws_scripts/output_files/
#aws_scripts/source_files/
```

Result in `git status`:

```
git status
On branch develop
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/develop'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   aws_scripts/python/aws_tools/__pycache__/ec2_mongo.cpython-39.pyc

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        .gitignore
        .vscode/
        aws_scripts/output_files/
        aws_scripts/source_files/
```

Why is only the `__pycache__` directory not working with `.gitignore`?

Comment: You can't ignore tracked files.

Comment: These directories are untracked: `Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        .gitignore
        .vscode/
        aws_scripts/output_files/
        aws_scripts/source_files/`

But they disappear when I add them to `.gitignore` andI do a git status.

Comment: `aws_scripts/python/aws_tools/__pycache__/ec2_mongo.cpython-39.pyc` is a tracked file, otherwise git wouldn't list it as _modified_.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Notice the `modified` in your `git status` output. That means you already added and commited the `__pycache__`.

`git rm -rf <PATH>` it, commit and it should start to be properly ignored.

It is not a bad idea to start with official `.gitignore`s from the beginning and extend those: https://github.com/github/gitignore

Comment: I had to add a -f to force it to work, but it did the trick.  Thanks
git rm -r -f __pycache__